# Separating axis theorem

Tags: java, math, geometry, axis

I'm trying to get my head around this- and I've literally been looking for a whole day!

I think I understand the main concepts behind it, but I'm struggling to figure out the math I need to create the axis on which to project my shapes on to?

So if I have a rectange I find out each of the points and then use these to find the side of the shape `edge = v(n) - v(n-1)` and go through all sides.

But I don't know how to then create the separating axis.

Comment: Less a Java question and more a pure math question, no?

Comment: Potentially, but I will be attempting to implement it in Java afterwards - I guess I was blindly hoping someone would have a java example!

Comment: Probably best to just worry about the math first though; one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem is not difficult to understand: If you can find a line for which all points of shape A are on the one side, and all points of shape B are on the other (dot product positive or negative), that line is separating the shapes.

What do you want to do? Find separating lines for arbitrary shapes?

I would recommend to have a look at projective geometry, as the edge for two vertices of a polygon extended to infinity can be represented by the cross product of the two vertices (x, y, 1). For convex polygons you can simply create lines for all edges and then take the dot product of all vertices of your other polygon to check on which side they are. If for one edge all points are outside, that edge is a separating line.

Also keep in mind that by keeping the line normalized you get the distance of a point to the line using dot product. The sign identifies the side on which the point lies.

If your problem is more difficult, please explain it in more detail. Maybe you can use some sort of clipping to solve it fast.

**Example: projective geometry**

```
public double[] e2p(double x, double y) {
    return new double[] { x, y, 1 };
}

// standard vector maths
public double[] getCrossProduct(double[] u, double[] v) {
    return new double[] { u[1] * v[2] - u[2] * v[1],
            u[2] * v[0] - u[0] * v[2], u[0] * v[1] - u[1] * v[0] };
}

public double getDotProduct(double[] u, double[] v) {
    return u[0] * v[0] + u[1] * v[1] + u[2] * v[2];
}

// collision check
public boolean isCollision(List<Point2D> coordsA, List<Point2D> coordsB) {
    return !(isSeparate(pointsA, pointsB) || isSeparate(pointsB, pointsA));
}

// the following implementation expects the convex polygon's vertices to be in counter clockwise order
private boolean isSeparate(List<Point2D> coordsA, List<Point2D> coordsB) {
    edges: for (int i = 0; i < coordsA.size(); i++) {
        double[] u = e2p(coordsA.get(i).getX(), coordsA.get(i).getY());
        int ni = i + 1 < coordsA.size() ? i + 1 : 0;
        double[] v = e2p(coordsA.get(ni).getX(), coordsA.get(ni).getY());
        double[] pedge = getCrossProduct(u, v);
        for (Point2D p : coordsB) {
            double d = getDotProduct(pedge, e2p(p.getX(), p.getY()));
            if (d > -0.001) {
                continue edges;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 'For convex polygons you can simply create lines for all edges and then take the dot product of all vertices of your other polygon to check on which side they are. ' Thats what I need to figure out - how to create the line - given the vertices of the side ?

Comment: Suppose you have vertices (10, 5) and (20, 0) => convert to projective points => (10, 5, 1) and (20, 0, 1) => take cross product => (5, 10, -100). <5, 10, -100> is your line. Now check sign of dot product of this line with another point of shape A and compare it to the sign of the dot product of the line with points of shape B.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - I'm a bit unsure why you change the vertices to have the extra parameter (1)?

Comment: Also I need to use sat for collision detection - so thats why I needed to figure out the axis.

Comment: The extra parameter is why I recommend to have a look at projective geometry. In planar projective space, points and lines are represented by 3-dimensional, euclidean lines and planes, which go through the origin. These 3d lines and planes are intersected with the z=1 plane to yield 3d points and lines. The vector <x,y,z> therefore can represent either a 2-dimensional point or line. In the case of a point, the vector <x,y,z> is the direction of the 3d line. In the case of a line, the vector <x,y,z> is normal to the 3d plane.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense.  Unlike [this] tutorial I have been trying to follow.[this]:https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169

Answer (score 0):

The separating axis is one of the sides. You can find the signs of the vertexes of the shape itself when plugged in the equation of this side:

```
(X - Xn).(Y - Yn-1) - (X - Xn-1).(Y - Yn) = 0
```

Check that the vertices of the other shape yield opposite signs.